# Wordpress Next Post doesn't always link to correct post & if last post

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by, custom-post-type

I have a website with custom post types, this specific post type I am working with is "News". I have a list of News posts which are displaying as they should, (in descending order of their publish date). However, for some reason I can't get the get_next_post() function to work correctly. It's actually working for 90% of the posts, however the newest two posts it seems to be completely skipping. I will be on post 1 and it links next post to post 3 instead of post 2.

This is how I am displaying my list of posts:

```
$args = array("post_type" => "news", 'posts_per_page' => 5, "paged" => $paged, "orderby" => "date", "order" => "DESC");
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

My single post pages is single-news.php. It's not in a loop or anything, it just uses the $post variable to get all of the information for the posts.

I am using get_permalink(get_next_post()->ID) to get the permalink, however like i stated above it's not always correct.

I hope that's enough information for that issue, but alongside this I would also like to be able to detect on the single post page if it's the last post in the News post type so I can remove the Next Post button.

Comment: did you try `query_posts` ?

Comment: Yes I did, but that didn't seem to help anything. And this query is unrelated to the single-news page

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with your code , the best way to use navigation is

`<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>` or

```
<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>
```

For more information go through this

http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post

Thanks.